# Re:How to calculate the 90th percentile of a column corresponding to another column having same characters using R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

```
x<-read.csv("input_file.csv")
```

It looks like..[After reading the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sxKV.png)

So to calculate the 90TH PERCENTILE of time column wrt to name column having same characters..I used this:

```
aggregate(df$Time, by=list(Name=df$Name), FUN=function(x) quantile(x, probs =0.9))
```

but it gives a error like:

```
Error in df$Time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

please help.

Comment: `df` is also a internal function in `R` hence should be avoided for data.frame names. Try with `DF <-read.csv("input_file.csv");aggregate(DF$Time, by=list(Name=DF$Name), FUN=function(someVarName) quantile(someVarName, probs =0.9))`,

Comment: You called your object `x` and then used `df` inside `aggregate`...